# UI not being updated by the result of fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to load search results based on what the user typed (responsive search), I thought it was my event as I wanted it more responsive e.g `keyup` but it didn't work. Here is working [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/NWNLvpg?editors=1111)
and following in my code. I had been struggling for hours now. What am I doing wrong?

```
function generateHTML(el,toggleClass){
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const card = div.classList.add("card","col-sm-6", "col-md-6", "col-lg-3", "m-2",toggleClass);
    div.innerHTML = `
        <a href='#' class="products"> 
        <img src="${el.image}" class="card-img-top rounded" alt="${el.title}">
         <div class="card-body">
             <h5 class="card-title">${(slicer(el.title))}</h5>
         </div>
         </a>
    `
    grid.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you actually want

```js
//getting the reference to elements
const row = document.querySelector("#search");
const grid = document.querySelector("#grid");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const formGroup = div.classList.add("form-group");
    div.innerHTML = `        
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            <label for="searchField">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchField" placeholder="Type in what your looking for">
        </div>
        `;
    row.appendChild(div);

    //fetchData()

    //get the reference to form
    var input = '';
    const myInput = document.getElementById("searchField");
    myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
        input = myInput.value;
        console.log(input);
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/')
            //convert the response to JSON
            .then(res => res.json())
            //use the data to filter if it matches or display all
            .then(data => {
                grid.innerHTML = '';
                data.forEach(el => {
                    if (el.title.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
                        console.log('h')
                        generateHTML(el, "block")
                    }
                })
            })
    });
    //get the reference to input
    //const input = form.searchField.value.trim();
    //add a event to listen on key up
})


function generateHTML(el, toggleClass) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const card = div.classList.add("card", "col-sm-6", "col-md-6", "col-lg-3", "m-2", toggleClass);
    div.innerHTML = `
        <a href='#' class="products"> 
            <img src="${el.image}" class="card-img-top rounded" alt="${el.title}" width="100" height="auto">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${(slicer(el.title))}</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        `;
    grid.appendChild(div);
}

function slicer(str) {
    return str.slice(0, 10);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="" id="search">

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="grid">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, so I guess 2 things I noticed (might missed something) 1. you made the innerHTML empty and then u used lowercase to match both?

Comment: yes you are right and also the request happens on keyup event.

Comment: thnx. just wondering. if we want to display all items by default n filter on keyup, will we make it in same call or it has to be another call?

Comment: if you want to show the data on page load by default, you need an another call on document load event. Or you just get all data on document load event. then perform a search on fetched data. So you will not need to make a call every time you press a key.